# Component lifecycle's 'render' stage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, lifecycle

I have recently started learning React.js and am currently on the topic of component lifecycle. Forgive me if I'm wrong about my explanation.

I feel I understand the basics of the component lifecycle methods (hopefully) from the componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate phases.

The course I am learning from shows me an example of the lifecycle (please see the screenshot below) when the value 'Max' is changed to 'Maxi'. I have edited it to show how the components are rendered (in terms of parent and child components).

[image: Please see example below]

From my understanding from the screenshot, when the value of Person.js component changes, the lifecycle methods start from the top of the component tree (App.js).

Notice `[App.js] render`.

I see that from this, Persons.js is the only component being re-rendered? (you can see the elements highlighted in green which identify which parts were rendered.)

So am I correct in saying `[App.js] render` isn't re-rendering the whole App component to apply that 'Maxi' change, only Persons.js?
If so:

- What does it do at that stage?
- does it render in to the virtual DOM but not on the actual DOM?

If `[App.js] render` DOES re-render it and its child's to apply the 'Maxi' change :

- Why can't React start the component lifecycle from Persons.js? instead of at the top of the component tree App.js?

Answer (score 0):

[React class component lifecylce](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class)
[image: React class component lifecylce]

React Hook lifecylce
[image]